# Heroku no puede ejercutar chromium Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, nodejs, heroku, puppeteer

Intento desplegar en Heroku la app con Puppeteer, pero al momento de desplegarlo en los logs de la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

Puppeteer app detected
remote: -----> Reusing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: E: List directory /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/apt/state/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)

tengo entendido que son algunas dependencias de linux (estoy en window)
Lo que logro entender es que intenta instalar unas dependencias que esta en ese directorio, pero tal directorio no existe.  Luego procede a intentar instalar dependencias y todas salen con el siguiente mensaje :

Fetching .debs for libgraphite2-3
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote: E: Archives directory /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/apt/cache/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)
remote:        Reinstallation of libgraphite2-3 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.

Varia el nombre de todas las dependencias obviamente.
Al final del proceso, cuando ejecuto la aplicacion desde heroku, me aparece el siguiente mensaje dede los logs:

/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-848005/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Logro entender que intenta ejecutar un chrome que esta en ese directorio, pero en mis node_modules no aparece el directorio linux-848005/chrome-linux/chrome, sino que me aparece el win64-848005/chrome-win y en él me aparecen varios archivos con extenciones .exe y .dll

Viendo en la pagina de puppeteer me indican que hay que agregar cierta configuración al browser.launch, he intentado de con dicha configuración pero sigue dando el mismo error.
Adjunto mi código:

```js
router.get('/consumo', async(req, res) => {
    await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'] }).then(async navegador => {
            const pagina = await navegador.newPage()
            await pagina.setViewport({ width: 1535, height: 756 })
            await pagina.goto('http://controlmagistral.dyndns.info/control_magistral_alphalab/index.php')

            //Login
            await pagina.type('input[type= "text"]', process.env.ID)
            await pagina.type('input[type= "password"]', process.env.PASS)
            await pagina.click('input[type= "submit"]')

            await pagina.waitForSelector(`td[align="LEFT"] p`)

            const data = await pagina.evaluate(() => {
                let nombres = document.querySelectorAll(`td[align="LEFT"] p`)
                let consumos = document.querySelectorAll(`td[align="CENTER"]:nth-child(4) p`)

                let arr = []
                let cantidades = []
                for (let nombre of nombres) {
                    let elemento = nombre.innerText.trim()
                    arr.push({ 'item': elemento })
                }
                for (let consumo of consumos) {
                    let numero = consumo.innerText.trim()
                    cantidades.push(numero)
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (!arr[i].cantidad) {
                        arr[i].cantidad = cantidades[i]
                    } else {
                        arr[i].cantidad = cantidades[i]
                    }
                }
                //Rotorna todos los nombres de cada elemento de la tabla
                return arr
            })
            if (data) {
                res.send({ data: data })
                navegador.close()
            } else {
                res.send('Ocurrio un error')
                navegador.close()
            }
           
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('HUBO UN ERROR', err);
        })
```

Espero haber expuesto mi problema correctamente!

Answer (score 1):

Resolví el problema desplegando la aplicación desde la consola original de Windows (cmd)
Anteriormente lo había hecho desde git bash.
Aparentemente eso resolvió mi problema y pude instalar todas las dependencias.
Espero esto le sirva a alguien.
Saludos